# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize' of null

Tags: jquery

I'm on joomla using RT_dominion template from roketthemes ans their roksproket plugin, i get this jquery error where i display a roksproket slider:

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize'

```
Element.implement({
    'styles': function(){
        var mu = moofx(this), result = mu.style.apply(mu, arguments);
        if (arguments.length == 1 && typeof arguments[0] == 'string') return result;
        return this;
    },
    'moofx': function(){
        var mu = moofx(this);
        mu.animate.apply(mu, arguments);
        return this;
    }
});

var Sliders = new Class({

    Implements: [Options, Events],

    animations: {},

    options: {
        data: 'accordion',
        settings: {}
    },

    initialize: function(options){
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.data = this.options.data;

        this.sliders = document.getElements('[data-' + this.data + ']');
        this.settings = {};
        this.timers = {};
        this.statuses = {};
    },

    attach: function(feature, settings){
        feature = typeOf(feature) == 'number' ?
                    document.getElements('[data-' + this.data + '=' + this.getID(feature) + ']')
                    :
                    feature;
        settings = typeOf(settings) == 'string' ? JSON.decode(settings) : settings;

        var containers = (feature ? new Elements([feature]).flatten() : this.sliders);

        containers.each(function(container){
            container.store('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached', true);

            this.setSettings(container, settings, 'restore');

            var relay = {
                mouseenter: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':mouseenter', function(event){
                    this.stopTimer.call(this, container);
                    this.pause.call(this, container);
                }.bind(this)),

                mouseleave: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':mouseleave', function(event){
                    this.resume.call(this, container);
                    this.startTimer.call(this, container);
                }.bind(this)),

                next: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':next', function(event, element){
                    this.direction.call(this, event, container, element, 'next');
                }.bind(this)),

                previous: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':previous', function(event, element){
                    this.direction.call(this, event, container, element, 'previous');
                }.bind(this)),

                item: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':item', function(event, element){
                    var position = container.getElements('[data-'+this.data+'-item]').indexOf(element);
                    this.toPosition(container, position);
                }.bind(this))
            };

            ['mouseenter', 'mouseleave'].each(function(type){
                container.addEvent(type, relay[type]);
            });

            ['next', 'previous'].each(function(dir, i){
                var query = '[data-' + this.data + '-' + dir + ']';
                if (i > 0) query += ', [data-' + dir + ']';

                container.addEvent('click:relay(' + query + ')', relay[dir]);
            }, this);

            container.addEvent('click:relay([data-' + this.data + '-item])', relay.item);

            if (container.getElements('[data-'+this.data+'-item]').length > 1) this.showArrows(container);

            this.toPosition(container, 0, true);

            if (this.getSettings(container).autoplay && this.getSettings(container).autoplay.toInt()) this.startTimer(container);

        }, this);
    },


    detach: function(feature){
        feature = typeOf(feature) == 'number' ?
                    document.getElements('[data-' + this.data + '=' + this.getID(feature) + ']')
                    :
                    feature;

        var containers = (feature ? new Elements([feature]).flatten() : this.sliders);

        containers.each(function(container){
            container.store('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached', false);
            var relay = {
                mouseenter: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':mouseenter'),
                mouseleave: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':mouseleave'),
                pagination: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':relay'),
                next: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':next'),
                previous: container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':previous')
            };

            ['mouseenter', 'mouseleave'].each(function(type){
                container.removeEvent(type, relay[type]);
            });

            ['pagination', 'next', 'previous'].each(function(dir, i){
                var query = '[data-' + this.data + '-' + dir + ']';
                if (i > 0) query += ', [data-' + dir + ']';

                container.removeEvent('click:relay(' + query + ')', relay[dir]);
            }, this);

        }, this);
    },

    setSettings: function(container, settings, restore){
        var id = this.getID(container),
            options = Object.clone(this.options.settings);

        if (!restore || !this.settings['id-' + id]){
            this.settings['id-' + id] = Object.merge(options, settings || options);
        }
    },

    getSettings: function(container){
        var id = this.getID(container);

        return this.settings['id-' + id];
    },

    getContainer: function(container){
        if (!container) container = document.getElements('[data-' + this.data + ']');
        if (typeOf(container) == 'number') container = document.getElement('[data-' + this.data + '='+container+']');
        if (typeOf(container) == 'string') container = document.getElement(container);

        return container;
    },

    getID: function(id){
        if (typeOf(id) == 'number') id = document.getElement('[data-' + this.data + '='+id+']');
        if (typeOf(id) == 'string') id = document.getElement(id);
        return !id ? id : id.get('data-' + this.data);
    },

    toPosition: function(container, position, force){
        container = this.getContainer(container);
        if (!container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached')) return;

        this.stopTimer(container);

        var settings = this.getSettings(container),
            sliders  = container.getElements('[data-' + this.data + '-item]'),
            current  = container.getElement('[data-' + this.data + '-item].active'),
            closed   = container.getElement('[data-' + this.data + '-item]:not(.active)'),
            height   = settings.height_fixed;

        if (!sliders.length) return;

        if (sliders[position] && sliders[position].hasClass('active') && !force) return;

        if (position > sliders.length - 1) position = 0;
        if (position < 0) position = sliders.length - 1;

        if (sliders.length){
            if (settings.height_control == 'auto') height = (force) ? sliders[position].getSize().y : sliders[position].getFirst().getSize().y;

            var closedHeight = closed.getSize().y;
            current.moofx({height: closedHeight}, {duration: '300ms', equation: 'ease-in-out'});
            sliders.removeClass('active');
            sliders[position].addClass('active').setStyle('height', closedHeight);
            sliders[position].moofx({height: height}, {duration: '300ms', equation: 'ease-in-out'});
        }

        if (settings.autoplay && settings.autoplay.toInt()) this.startTimer(container);
    },

    direction: function(event, container, element, dir){
        if (event) event.preventDefault();

        dir = dir || 'next';
        this[dir](container, element);
    },

    showArrows: function(){
        var args = Array.slice(arguments),
            container = $(args[0]);
            arrows = args.splice(1);

        if (!arrows.length) arrows = ['next', 'previous'];

        arrows.forEach(function(arrow){
            arrow = container.getElement('[data-' + this.data + '-' + arrow + ']');
            if (arrow) arrow.setStyle('visibility', 'visible');
        }, this);
    },

    next: function(container, element){
        container = this.getContainer(container);
        if (!container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached')) return;
        if (typeOf(container) == 'elements') return this.nextAll(container, element);

        var sliders = container.getElements('[data-' + this.data + '-item]');
        if (!sliders.length) return;

        var active = sliders.filter(function(page){ return page.hasClass('active'); }),
            position = sliders.indexOf(active.length ? active[0] : '') || 0,
            next = position + 1;

        if (next > sliders.length - 1) next = 0;
        this.toPosition(container, next);
    },

    nextAll: function(containers, element){
        containers = this.getContainer(containers);
        if (typeOf(containers) == 'element') return this.next(containers, element);

        containers.each(function(container){
            this.next(container, element);
        }, this);
    },

    previous: function(container, element){
        container = this.getContainer(container);
        if (!container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached')) return;

        if (typeOf(container) == 'elements') return this.previousAll(container, element);

        var sliders = container.getElements('[data-' + this.data + '-item]');
        if (!sliders.length) return;

        var active = sliders.filter(function(page){ return page.hasClass('active'); }),
            position = sliders.indexOf(active.length ? active[0] : '') || 0,
            previous = position - 1;

        if (previous < 0) previous = sliders.length - 1;
        this.toPosition(container, previous);
    },

    previousAll: function(containers, element){
        containers = this.getContainer(containers);
        if (typeOf(containers) == 'element') return this.previous(containers, element);

        containers.each(function(container){
            this.previous(container, element);
        }, this);
    },

    startTimer: function(container){
        container = this.getContainer(container);
        if (!container.retrieve('roksprocket:' + this.data + ':attached')) return;

        var settings = this.getSettings(container),
            id = this.getID(container),
            status = this.statuses['id-' + id],
            autoplay = settings.autoplay.toInt(),
            delay = (settings.delay.toInt()) * 1000;

        clearTimeout(this.timers['id-' + id]);
        if (autoplay && status != 'pause') this.timers['id-' + id] = this.next.delay(delay, this, container);
    },

    stopTimer: function(container){
        container = this.getContainer(container);

        var id = this.getID(container);
        clearTimeout(this.timers['id-' + id]);
    },

    pause: function(container){
        container = this.getContainer(container);

        var id = this.getID(container);
        this.statuses['id-' + id] = 'pause';
    },

    resume: function(container){
        container = this.getContainer(container);

        var id = this.getID(container);
        this.statuses['id-' + id] = 'play';
    }

});

this.RokSprocket.Sliders = Sliders;
```

Comment: Please add some more details.

Comment: ok, my website is http://ravenguild.net - there is on the top a slider .. it's not working, i used firebug to see what's wrong and i found the error on my first question. what details do you need ?

Comment: Sharing website wont help. I need some subset i.e. the problematic code

Comment: well i edited the question is that ok ?